# Prove a set of 2m elements has a total number of subsets of 4^m

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need to prove that if a set has $2n$ elements, then the total number of subsets that the set has is $4^n$. I understand that a power sets have $2^n$ subset however I'm unsure how to prove this using first principles.

Answer (score 1):

If a set with $n$ elements has $2^n$ subset, then apply this formula to $2m$, precisely:

$$2^{2m}=(2^2)^m=4^m.$$

Comment: You should correct $2^{2m}=2^{2^m}=4^m$ into $2^{2m}=(2^{2})^m=4^m$.